# Biblatex - \DeclareFieldFormat

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I'm writing a thesis in french law and I was able to, after many, many hours of hard work, customize some entry type to fit my needs. Here is my example of my `@BOOKLET` that I use for legislation:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[language=french,sorting=nyt,hyperref=true,urldate=long,
bibstyle=authortitle,citestyle=verbose-trad1,citepages=omit,dateabbrev=false,
labelyear=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{These.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{booklet}{%
\usebibmacro{author}
\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
\printfield{title}
\newunit\newblock
\printlist{publisher}%
\newunit
\printfield{number}%
\newunit
\printdate%
\newunit
\printfield{pages}%
{\space}
\usebibmacro{finentry}
 }

\DeclareFieldFormat[booklet]{title}{{{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[booklet]{publisher}{{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[booklet]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}% 
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=loi,heading=subbibliography,title=Textes législatifs]

\end{document}
```

It's almost how I want it, I'd just like to get the field `publisher` in italics, which is what was intended with the command:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[booklet]{publisher}{{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
```

But it doesn't change anything, and I don't know why, especially as if I replace `publisher` by `date` or `title`, it works just fine!

Any suggestions? I really need your expertise here ;-)

PS : Here an example of my .bib

```
@BOOKLET{AA2012,
TITLE = "The title of the legislation I need",
PUBLISHER = "Official journal",
NUMBER = "173",
DATE = "2012-11-25",
ADDRESS = "Paris",
PAGES = "582",
KEYWORDS = "loi"
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `publisher` isn't a field; it's a list. So you have to redefine the the original definition of `\DeclareListFormat{publisher}`

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your quick and effective answer... I've been trying for quite some time now... Can you tell me how can you know if your dealing with a field or a list, or a whatever?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Marco Daniel has commented, *"`publisher` isn't a field, but a [literal] list"*. Actually, there are three general types of "fields" in `biblatex`: name lists (e.g., `translator`), literal lists (e.g., `publisher`), and other fields. The format of literal lists can be defined using `\DeclareListFormat`, and that of other fields using `\DeclareFieldFormat`. (The correspondent `\DeclareNameFormat` macro isn't directly appplied to name lists, but to auxiliary formats like `last-first`.)
 A complete list of fields and their categories can be found in sections 2.2.1 and 2.2.2 of the `biblatex` manual.

Comment: With name formatting directives, that's just how the default formats are set up. The formatting code is applied to the name parts (passed as eight arguments) for each name in the list. Literal list formats are similar, but each list item is passed to the code as a single argument.